# History tables in .NET MVC code first approach?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, database, ef-code-first

I need to track a change history of some database objects in a MVC .NET application using the code first approach.

Here is what is meant by history table:
http://database-programmer.blogspot.de/2008/07/history-tables.html

I would use a history table for it, if I would write the SQL queries myself. But in the code first approach the SQL is generated... and I would like to stick to this paradigm.

The goal is a structure that holds all "old" revisions of changed/deleted entries together with some additional information (e.g. timestamp, user who changed it, ...)

Any ideas?

Regards,
Stefan

To be more specific - here is some code example:

```
public class Node {
 public int NodeID { get; set; }

 public string? data { get; set; }  // sample data
}


public class NodeHistory {
  public int NodeID { get; set; }
  public string? data { get; set; }

  public int UserID { get; set; }
  public DataTime timestamp { get; set; }
}
```

What I need is some "framework" assistance to be able to add an entry to NodeHistory whenever a change is -persisted- to table the Node structure.

That means: Just overriding the set-method isn't a solution, as it would also create an entry, if the change to a "Node" is not persisted at the end (e.g. roleback).

Comment: Don't feel like you're stuck with the SQL that's generated.  There is no harm in modifying the data layer to suit your needs, especially when there's no representation in the business layer.

Comment: I added some code, which explains what's the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the best approach for me would be to use a repository pattern and do the insertion into the NodeHistory table on every operation on the Node object that you see fit to keep a history of.

EDIT: Some code

```
public class NodeRepository{
    public Node EditNode(Node toEdit, int userId){
        using(new TransactionScope())
        {            
            //Edit Node in NodeContext like you would anyway without repository
            NodeContext.NodeHistories.Add(new NodeHistory(){//initialise NodeHistory stuff here)
            NodeContext.SaveChagnes();
        }
    }
}
public class NodeContext:DbContext{
    public DbSet<Node> Nodes{get;set;}
    public DbSet<NodeHistory> NodeHistories{get;set;}
}
```

If you are looking for something simpler than this, then I have no idea what it might be.

Comment: Looked up "repository pattern". At first glance this looks like what I need... will let you know if it's solving the issue. Any good tutorial on this, that you can suggest?

Comment: I had another good tutorial that I can not seem to locate at the moment if I do I will post it here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2009/06/16/using-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-with-entity-framework-4-0.aspx

Comment: Hm, seems that the "repository pattern" is a bit too complicated to understand. It should be a solution that's easy to understand, as not only I have to understand it, but others have to manage that code (without any explanations from me, except some comments in the source).

Comment: Is there maybe a way to derive a subclass of DbSet<> that does everything as normal, but can react to events (as "commit" or something like that)?

Comment: A repository is a class that exposes methods such as add/edit/delete and internally it uses your implementation of the DBContext class which you must have anyway, so in a way it acts as a wrapper to your DBContext. I will include a rough code section in my post for you

Comment: Okay, in that case I must have found something else than... had found this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649690.aspx and other complicated stuff.

Comment: Is there any other name of this software design pattern? => Didn't find it here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_design_pattern ; just found adapter/wrapper... which is maybe not adequate enough.

Comment: Here are some links that discuss this pattern in different forms: http://blog.lowendahl.net/?p=249  and http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/repository.html and this last one might be able to point you to few more: http://domaindrivendesign.org/search/node/repository%20pattern

Answer (score 1):

This is really something you should do with a trigger.  Yes, you have to write some sql for it, but then history is updated no matter how the update occurs, either manually, or through some other means.

Comment: I think there is not possibility to store the "userid" (who modified it), only with a trigger. I would need at least a stored procedure to hand over this parameter, but this would make all the "code first" paradigm useless. As I had to write the DB access functions myself, right?

Comment: @StefanK. - it depends on whether the app is running with Windows Authentication or not, and you're using ad authentication with your database.  How would you know who edited a record if they did so in Sql management studio?

Comment: The app is just a web frontend. The effective user is just known to the application. I could write an stored procedure for write access to the table...

Comment: @StefanK. - It doesn't matter whether it's "just a frontend" or not, what matters is the kind of authentication you're using.

Comment: What ever... it's definitively not using windows authentication for authenticating the user (=principal, whats needed to be logged) itself. But we'll use it to authenticate the applications user (under which the application is running) to access the database.